# Approximation of stochastic integral

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

Let $f \in C^2_C(\mathbb{R})$ and $$X_t = X_0 + \int_0^t \sigma(s) \, dB_s + \int_0^t b(s) \, ds$$ be an (one-dimensional) Itô process where $\sigma,b: [0,\infty) \times \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ progressively measurable and pathwise bounded. Let $(\tau_n)_n$ be a common localization sequence of $b$, $\sigma$. Then there exist sequences of simple processes $(\sigma^{\Pi})_{\Pi}$, $(b^{\Pi})_{\Pi}$ such that $$\sigma^{\Pi} \cdot 1_{[0,\tau_n)} \stackrel{L^2(\lambda_T \times \mathbb{P})}{\to} \sigma \cdot 1_{[0,\tau_n)} \qquad (|\Pi| \to 0) \\ b^{\Pi} \cdot 1_{[0,\tau_n)} \stackrel{L^2(\lambda_T \times \mathbb{P})}{\to}b \cdot 1_{[0,\tau_n)} \qquad (|\Pi| \to 0)$$
for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Denote by $X^{\Pi}$ the corresponding Itô process. Then one can actually show that $$\int_0^{t} \sigma^{\Pi}(s) \, dB_s \to \int_0^t \sigma(s) \, dB_s \qquad \quad \int_0^t b^{\Pi}(s) \, ds \to \int_0^t b(s) \, ds \tag{1}$$ as $|\Pi| \to 0$ where the limits are uniform in probability. Thus in particular, $X^{\Pi} \to X$ uniform in probability as $|\Pi| \to 0$

In a proof of Itô's formula for Itô processes,

$$f(X_t)-f(X_0)= \int_0^t f'(X_s) \sigma(s) \, dB_s + \int_0^t f'(X_s)  b(s) \, ds + \frac{1}{2} \int_0^t f''(X_s) \sigma^2(s) \, ds \tag{2}$$

the author claims that it suffices to prove the formula for Itô processes where $b$, $\sigma$ are simple processes, because one can approximate (uniform in probability) an arbitrary Itô process by such processes, as already mentioned.

I don't see why the right-hand side in $(2)$ converges also uniform in probability, i.e. why $$\mathbb{P} \left( \sup_{0 \leq t \leq T} \left| \int_0^t f'(X_s^{\Pi}) \cdot \sigma^{\Pi}(s) \, dB_s - \int_0^t f'(X_s) \cdot \sigma(s) \, dB_s \right| > \varepsilon \right) \to 0 \tag{3}$$ 
as $|\Pi| \to 0$. It looks similar to the statement in $(1)$, but there I can apply the maximum inequality and Itô isometry since I know that $\sigma^{\Pi} \cdot 1_{[0,\tau_n)} \to \sigma \cdot 1_{[0,\tau_n)}$ in $L^2(\lambda_T \times \mathbb{P})$. Whereas in this case, I have $f'(X_s^{\Pi}) \to f'(X_s)$ uniform in probability, but as far as I can see no convergence in $L^2(\lambda_T \times \mathbb{P})$. How to conclude $(3)$...?

Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do we get $\sigma^\Pi 1_{[0,\tau_n)} \to \sigma 1_{[0,\tau_n)}$? I know that $\sigma 1_{[0,\tau_n)}$ being in $L^2(\lambda_T \times P)$ meanse that it can be approximated by a simple process, and that gives $\sigma^\Pi \to \sigma 1_{[0,\tau_n)}$. But how can we ensure that this simple process $\sigma^\Pi$ multiplied by $1_{[0,\tau_n)}$ still converges to the same limit?

Comment: @nomadicmathematician If $f_{\Pi} \to f$ in $L^2$, then $f_{\Pi} g \to fg$ in $L^2$ for any $g \in L^{\infty}$. Use this for $f_{\Pi} = \sigma^{\Pi}$, $f=\sigma 1_{[0,\tau_n)}$ and $g = 1_{[0,\tau_n)}$.

Comment: How do you prove that $\int_0^t f'(X_s^{\Pi}) b^\Pi(s)ds$ converges uniformly in probability to $\int_0^t f'(X_s) b(s)ds$? This isn't clear to me because the argument for the stochastic integrals involve using Doob's inequality, which gets rid of the $\sup$ over $t\le T$, and we can use Chebyshev inequality and Ito's isometry to simplify matters. But for Riemann integrals, we cannot do the same so I can't figure out a way to get rid of the supremum. Also, I can't figure out how we can choose the partitions same for $\sigma$ and $b$ and independent of $n$ in $\tau_n$.

Comment: Indeed, I just wrote a question regarding this and found your answer. If you have time, please check : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3550113/question-about-schillings-proof-in-uniform-approximation-of-ito-processes-by-si

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, the proof is indeed similar to the proof of $(1)$. It's based on the fact that convergence in probability implies almost sure convergence of a subsequence. Set

$$\tau_n := \inf\left\{t \geq 0; \int_0^t |\sigma(s)|^2 \, ds + \int_0^t |b(s)|^2 \, ds \geq n \right\}.\tag{4}$$

By Doob's inequality, Itô's isometry and Tschbysheff inequality we have

$$\begin{align} & \quad \mathbb{P} \left( \sup_{t \leq T} \left| \int_0^t (f'(X_s^{\Pi}) \cdot \sigma^{\Pi}(s) - f'(X_s) \cdot \sigma(s)) \, dB_s \right| > \varepsilon \right) \\ &\leq \mathbb{P} \left( \sup_{t \leq T} \left| \int_0^{t \wedge \tau_n} (f'(X_s^{\Pi}) \cdot \sigma^{\Pi}(s) - f'(X_s) \cdot \sigma(s)) \, dB_s \right| > \varepsilon, \tau_n > T \right) + \mathbb{P}(\tau_n \leq T) \\ &\leq \frac{4}{\varepsilon^2} \cdot \underbrace{\mathbb{E} \left( \int_0^{T \wedge \tau_n} |f'(X_s^{\Pi}) \cdot \sigma^{\Pi}(s) - f'(X_s) \cdot \sigma(s)|^2 \, ds \right)}_{=:I} + \mathbb{P}(\tau_n \leq T) \end{align} $$

(Note that the boundedness of $f'$ implies the existence of the integrals.) Since \begin{align*} f'(X_s^{\Pi}) \cdot \sigma^{\Pi}(s) - f'(X_s) \cdot \sigma(s) &= f'(X_s^{\Pi}) \cdot \big(\sigma^{\Pi}(s)-\sigma(s)\big) \\ &\quad + \sigma(s) \cdot \big(f'(X_s^{\Pi})-f'(X_s) \big)\end{align*} and $(a+b)^2 \leq 2a^2+2b^2$ we obtain $$\begin{align*} I &\leq 2 \mathbb{E} \bigg( \int_0^{T \wedge \tau_n} \underbrace{|f'(X_s^{\Pi})|^2}_{\leq \|f'\|^2_{\infty}} \cdot |\sigma^{\Pi}(s)-\sigma(s)|^2 \, ds \bigg)\\ &\quad + 2 \mathbb{E} \left( \int_0^{T \wedge \tau_n} \sigma^2(s) \cdot |f'(X_s^{\Pi})-f'(X_s)|^2 \, ds \right) \end{align*}$$

The first addend converges to $0$ as $|\Pi| \downarrow 0$ since $\sigma^{\Pi} \cdot 1_{[0,\tau_n)} \to \sigma \cdot 1_{[0,\tau_n)}$ in $L^2(\lambda_T \times \mathbb{P})$ by assumption. For the second one, we note that

\begin{align*} \int_0^{T \wedge \tau_n} \sigma^2(s) |f'(X_s^{\Pi})-f'(X_s))|^2 \, ds &\leq \sup_{s \leq T}|f'(X_s^{\Pi})-f'(X_s))|^2  \int_0^{\tau_n} |\sigma(s)|^2 \, ds \\ &\leq n \sup_{s \leq T}|f'(X_s^{\Pi})-f'(X_s))|^2 \end{align*}

Since $X^{\Pi} \to X$ uniformly in probability, it follows from the continuity of $f'$ that the right-hand side converges to $0$ in probability as $|\Pi| \to 0$. Moreover,  by the above estimate,

$$\int_0^{T \wedge \tau_n} \sigma^2(s) |f'(X_s^{\Pi})-f'(X_s))|^2 \,d s \leq 2n \|f'\|_{\infty} \in L^1(\mathbb{P})$$

and so Vitali's convergence theorem gives

$$ \mathbb{E} \left( \int_0^{T \wedge \tau_n} \sigma^2(s) \cdot |f'(X_s^{\Pi})-f'(X_s)|^2 \, ds \right)  \to 0$$

Similarily, one can prove the convergence of the other addends in the right-hand side of $(2)$.

Comment: Thanks for giving such a detailed answer! 2 Question: 1) Where is the subsequence coming into play? 2) From what follows uniform integrability required by Vitali's convergence theorem?

Comment: @user4514 1. Ouh, I guess I decided to do it without subsequences (right now, I believe that we do not even need Vitali if we use the subsequence principle, but I have to check this). 2. We know that$$Z_{\Pi}:= \int_0^{T \wedge \tau_n} \sigma^2 |f'(X_s^{\Pi}-f'(X_s)|^2 \, ds \stackrel{\mathbb{P}}{\to} 0$$Moreover, since $\tau_n$ is a localizing sequence and $f'$ is bounded, we have$$|Z_{\Pi}| \leq T n 4 \|f'\|_{\infty}^2, $$ so we even have $$\sup_{\Pi} \|Z_{\Pi}\|_{L^{p}}<\infty$$ for all $p>1$. (If you find the answer/question helpful, you can upvoite it by clicking on the arrow next to it.)

Comment: So it even follows from dominated convergence?

Comment: @user4514 No, but my last comment shows that uniform integrability is satisfied. (Note that we only know $Z_{\Pi} \to 0$ in probability; not $Z_{\Pi} \to 0$ almost surely - therefore we cannot apply dominated convergence theorem.) [However, if we use subsequences, then it should follow from the dominated convergence theorem; yes.]

Comment: Ok, but doesn't Vitali's convergence also require almost sure convergence?

Comment: Also, I fail to see why finiteness of the supremum is needed, as it is not sufficient for uniform integrability?

Comment: @user4514 No, Vitali doesn't require almost sure convergence. Concerning uniform integrability: $$\sup_n \|X_n\|_{L^p}<\infty$$ for some $p>1$ implies that $(X_n)_n$ is uniformly integrable; right?

Comment: Yes, by de la Vallée Poussin, but in this case it simply should follow from boundedness

Comment: @user4514 Yeah, sure.

Comment: @saz In your first comment, why do we get $Z_\Pi \to 0$ in probability from the fact that the integrands converge to $0$ uniformly in probability? And why do you get the $Tn$ bound on $|Z_\Pi|$?

Comment: @nomadicmathematician 1) You can e.g. use the dominated convergence theorem/Vitali's convergence theorem to show this. 2) What makes you worried about the bound? There might be a square missing (i.e. $n^2$ instead of $n$). Doesn't change anything about the line of reasoning, though, since $n$ is fixed.

Comment: @saz 1) Don't we need almost sure convergence to use dominated convergence? And uniform integrability for Vitali's convergence theorem. But it isn't immediate to me how we get uniform integrability of $\sigma^2 |f'(X_s^\Pi)-f'(X_s)|^2 1_{[0,\tau_n)}$ for the partitions $\Pi$.  2) Do you mean $\sigma^2 1_{[0,\tau_n)} \le n$? I don't see a particular form of the localizing sequence $\tau_n$ here that gives this bound.

Comment: @saz Actually, I don't follow how you get $\sup_{s \le t} |\sigma^2(s) (f'(X_s^{\Pi})- f'(X_s)|^2 \to 0$ in probability. Continuity of $f'$ and uniform convergence in probability gives $\sup_{s \le t} |(f'(X_s^{\Pi})- f'(X_s)|^2 \to 0$ in probability, but how is this limit preserved even when $\sigma^2$ is multiplied?

Comment: @nomadicmathematician I will take a look into it when I have more time. It was quite a while ago that I wrote this question/answer and I need to recall the details... then I will also have a look at your question (if you haven't yet solved it on your own or somebody else answered it).

Comment: @saz Thank you very much appreciated. There are some details towards the end of this book that are quite difficult to fill in for me.

Comment: @nomadicmathematician Since $\sigma$ is pathwise bounded, we can choose the localizing sequence in such a way that $|\sigma(s,\omega)| \leq n$ for $s \leq \tau_n(\omega)$. This solves the issues which you mentioned in your first comment. (And no, dominated convergence does not require almost sure convergence; it is enough to have convergence in probability, this is a consequence of Vitali's convergence theorem). Re your 2nd comment: I know only claim that $$\sup_{s \leq t \color{red}{\wedge \tau_n}} |\sigma^2(s) (f'(X_s^{\Pi})-f'(X_s))|^2 \to 0$$ in probability.

Comment: .. this enough for what we want to do and follows from the fact that $|\sigma 1_{[0,\tau_n)}| \leq n$ and $\sup_{s \leq t} |f'(X_s^{\Pi})-f'(X_s)| \to 0$ in probability.

Comment: I think I follow your argument. This is the Vitali's theorem I found: If $u_n \to u$ in probability and $|u_n|,|u|\le w$ for some $w$ in $L^p$, then $u_n \to u$ in $L^p$. So to apply this, for each $n$, $1_{[0,T]}1_{[0,\tau_n)}\sigma^2(s)|f'(X_s^\Pi)-f'(X_s)|^2 \to 0$ in probability and is bounded by $Tn^2 4||f'||_\infty^2$ for almost all $s\le T\wedge \tau_n(\omega)$ and $\omega$, so we have $E[\int_0^{T \wedge \tau_n} \sigma^2(s)|f'(X_s^\Pi)-f'(X_s)|^2ds] \to 0$ as $|\Pi|\to 0$ by Vitali's convergence theorem. Is this correct?

Comment: One thing I don't get though is how we can ensure for all $\omega$, we have $|\sigma(s,\omega)|\le n$ for $s \le \tau_n(\omega$. Because pathwise bounded gives for each $\omega$, some $T$ and $K$:$|\sigma(s,\omega)| \le K$ for $s \in [0,T]$. So I can see that we can always take some $m$: $|\sigma(s,\omega)| \le n$ for $s \le \tau_m(\omega)$. But I can't show how to make this choice of $m$ independent of $\omega$ to ensure that we have $\tau_n$ for each bound $n$.

Comment: @nomadicmathematician Set $\tau_n := \inf\{t; |\sigma(t,\omega)| \geq n\}$, then $|\sigma 1_{[0,\tau_n)}| \leq n$.

Comment: @saz How do we ensure $\tau_n$ is a stopping time in this case? We usually require $\sigma$ to be continuous for hitting times on closed sets to be a stopping time.

Comment: @nomadicmathematician See my edited answer; I hope it finally answers your questions.

Answer (score 0):

So here we assume that $f$ is compactly supported and of $C^2$.

I will prove $$P(\sup_{0\le t \le T} | \int_0^t f''(X_s^\Pi) \sigma_\Pi^2(s)ds - \int_0^t f''(X_s)\sigma^2(s)ds|>\epsilon) \to 0.$$

The initial step is identical as in the first case by decomposing into sets of $\tau_n>T$ and $\tau_n\le T$. So consider the bound $P(\sup_{0\le t \le T} | \int_0^{t \wedge \tau_n} f''(X_s^\Pi) \sigma_\Pi^2(s) - f''(X_s)\sigma^2(s)ds|>\epsilon)\le P(\int_0^{T \wedge \tau_n}|f''(X_s^\Pi)\sigma_\Pi^2(s)-f''(X_s)\sigma^2(s)|ds>\epsilon).$

We take the localizing sequence in as the above answer, i.e.
$\tau_n=\inf \{t\ge 0: \int_0^t \sigma^2(s)ds + \int_0^t b^2(s) ds \ge n\}$. Then since we have by assumption, $\sigma_\Pi 1_{[0,\tau_n)} \to \sigma1_{[0,\tau_n)}$ in $L^2(\lambda_T \times P)$, we have $\sigma_\Pi^21_{[0,\tau_n)} \to \sigma^21_{[0,\tau_n)}$ in $L^1(\lambda_T \times P)$. Using Markov's inequality, we can bound the above by $\frac{1}{\epsilon}E\int_0^{T \wedge \tau_n}|f''(X_s^\Pi)\sigma_\Pi^2(s)-f''(X_s)\sigma^2(s)|ds$.

Now decompose the above to $\frac{1}{\epsilon}E\int_0^{T \wedge \tau_n}|f''(X_s^\Pi)(\sigma_\Pi^2(s)-\sigma^2(s))|ds+\frac{1}{\epsilon}E\int_0^{T \wedge \tau_n}|f''(X_s^\Pi)-f''(X_s)|\sigma^2(s)ds$.

The first integral is bounded by $||f''||_\infty \frac{1}{\epsilon}E\int_0^T 1_{[0,\tau_n)}|\sigma_\Pi^2(s)-\sigma^2(s)|ds$ and this $\to0$ as $|\Pi|\to 0$, since we have $\sigma_\Pi^21_{[0,\tau_n)} \to \sigma^21_{[0,\tau_n)}$ in $L^1(\lambda_T \times P)$.

For the next integral, we use  $\int_0^t \sigma^2(s)1_{[0,\tau_n)} \le n^2$ for all $s\le t$, and the uniform convergence of $X_s^\Pi$ to $X_s$ in probability and uniform continuity of $f''$ to conclude that
$f''(X_s^\Pi)$ converges to $f''(X_s)$ uniformly in probability as well. Also, we have $\int_0^{T \wedge \tau_n} |f''(X_s^\Pi) - f''(X_s)| \sigma^2(s)ds \le \sup_{s\le T} |f''(X_s^\Pi) -f''(X_s)| n$ and $\int_0^T|\sigma^2(s)(f''(X_s^\Pi)-f''(X_s))|1_{[0,\tau_n)} \le Tn4||f''||_\infty^2$ for almost all $\omega$ and $s\le T$, so by Vitali's convergence theorem which generalizes dominated convergence theorem to the case of convergence in probability, we get the second integral $\to 0$ as $|\Pi| \to 0$ as well.

The proof for the case of $\int_0^t f'(X_s) b(s)ds$ is identical.