# Question about Schilling's Proof in uniform approximation of Ito processes by simple Ito processes.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

I am trying to follow the proof of the following lemma from Rene Schilling's Brownian Motion and Stochastic Calculus. The setting is as below, where $\mathcal{L}_{T,loc}^2$ is the space of progressively measurable processes $f$ with a localizing sequence of stopping times $\tau_n$ that $\uparrow \infty$ a.s. and $f1_{[0,\tau_n)} \in \mathcal{L}_T^2$ for all $n \ge 0$. $\mathcal{L}_T^2$ is the progressively measurable $L^2$ functions in the measure space $\lambda_T \otimes P$, where $\lambda_T$ is the Lebesgue measure in $[0,T]$. In the following excerpt, simple processes refer to real-valued stochastic process $(f(t,\cdot))_{t \in [0,T]}$ of the form $$f(t,\omega)=\sum_{j=1}^n \phi_{j-1}(\omega)1_{[s_{j-1},s_j)}(t)$$where $n\ge 1$, $0=s_0\le s_1 \le \cdots \le s_n \le T$ and $\phi_j \in L^\infty (\mathcal{F}_{s_j})$ are bounded $\mathcal{F}_{s_j}$ measurable random variables, $j=0,\dots , n-1$. We write $\mathcal{S}_T$ for the family of all simple processes on $[0,T]$. We denote $\Pi$ as the partition of $[0,T]$ for the simple processes.

I have $2$ questions regarding the proof. First, how do we use a diagonal procedure to achive that the sequences $(b^\Pi)_\Pi, (\sigma^\Pi)_\Pi$ are independent of $n$? I cannot come up with an explicit construction of this.
Because usually to use diagonal argument, we would have, say the sequence of partitions $\Pi_2$ corresponding to $\tau_2$ be a subsequence of $\Pi_1$. But we don't have this here.

Finally, how can we calculate $$P\left( \sup_{t \le T} \left| \int_0^t (b_\Pi(s)-b(s)) \, ds \right|>\epsilon\right) \to_{|\Pi|\to 0} 0\text{?}$$
I tried imitating the proof for the case with $\sigma_\pi$, but the problem here is that we cannot use Doob's inequality as we don't have a martingale here. One thing I tried is to follow up to the third inequality as in the $\sigma$ case, and then bound \begin{align}
& P\left( \sup_{t \le T} \left| \int_0^{t\wedge \tau_n}(b_\Pi (s)-b(s)) \, ds \right| > \epsilon\right) \\[6pt]
\le {} & P\left(\sup_{t\le T} \int_0^{t \wedge \tau_n}| b_\Pi(s)-b(s)| \,ds>\epsilon\right) \\[6pt]
\le {} & P \left( \int_0^{T \wedge \tau_n}|b_\Pi (s)-b(s)| \, ds > \epsilon \right).
\end{align}

But I cannot really progress from here because if I use Chebyshev's inequality then I would need to take the square inside the integrand, which would require using Jensen's inequality but I'm not sure I can use this. This seems much more complicated than the previous calculation for $\sigma$. Is there any way to prove this? I would greatly appreciate some help.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the diagonalization: Let's consider the diffusion coefficient $\sigma$ (the reasoning for the drift is analogous). Since $\sigma 1_{[0,\tau_n)} \in \mathcal{L}^2_T$ there exists for each a simple process $g_n$ such that

$$\|g_n- \sigma 1_{[0,\tau_n)} \|_{L^2} \leq \frac{1}{n}.\tag{1}$$

> Claim: $g_n 1_{[0,\tau_k)} \to \sigma 1_{[0,\tau_k)}$ in $L^2$ for each $k \geq 1$.

Proof: For each $n \geq k$ we have

\begin{align*}\|g_n 1_{[0,\tau_k)} - \sigma 1_{[0,\tau_k)}\|_{L^2}^2 &= \mathbb{E} \int_0^{\tau_k} |g_n(s,\omega)-\sigma(s,\omega)|^2 \, ds \, d\mathbb{P}(\omega) \\ &\leq \mathbb{E} \int_0^{\tau_n} |g_n(s,\omega)-\sigma(s,\omega)|^2 \, ds \, d\mathbb{P}(\omega) \\ &\leq \mathbb{E} \int_0^{\tau_n} |g_n(s,\omega)-\sigma(s,\omega)|^2 \, ds \, d\mathbb{P}(\omega)  \\ &\quad +\mathbb{E} \int_{\tau_n}^{\infty} |g_n(s,\omega)-0|^2 \, ds \, d\mathbb{P}(\omega) \\ &= \|g_n- \sigma 1_{[0,\tau_n)}\|_{L^2}^2 \end{align*}

and so, by $(1)$,

$$\|g_n 1_{[0,\tau_k)} - \sigma 1_{[0,\tau_k)}\|_{L^2} \leq \frac{1}{n},$$ which proves the assertion. Consequently, $(g_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is the sequence of simple functions which we are looking for.

---

Regarding your question about the estimate for the drift: Yes, you need to apply Jensen's inequality. Note that, by Jensen's inequality,

$$\left( \int_0^t f(s) \, ds \right)^2 \leq t \int_0^t f(s)^2 \, ds \tag{2}$$

for each $t \geq 0$ and any (suitable integrable) function $f$. This gives

\begin{align*} \left| \int_0^{T \wedge \tau_n} |b^{\Pi}(s)-b(s)| \, ds \right|^2 &\leq (T \wedge \tau_n) \int_0^{T \wedge \tau_n} |b^{\Pi}(s)-b(s)|^2 \, ds \\ &\leq T \int_0^{T \wedge \tau_n} |b^{\Pi}(s)-b(s)|^2 \, ds. \tag{3}\end{align*}

Taking expectation we get

\begin{align*} \mathbb{E}\left(\left| \int_0^{T \wedge \tau_n} |b^{\Pi}(s)-b(s)| \, ds\right|^2 \right)\leq T \mathbb{E}\int_0^{T \wedge \tau_n} |b^{\Pi}(s)-b(s)|^2 \, ds,\end{align*}

and by construction the right-hand side converges to $0$ as $|\Pi| \to 0$. Hence, by Markov's inequality,

\begin{align*} \mathbb{P} \left( \int_0^{T \wedge \tau_n} |b^{\Pi}(s)-b(s)| \, ds > \epsilon \right) &\leq \frac{1}{\epsilon^2}\mathbb{E}\left(\left| \int_0^{T \wedge \tau_n} |b^{\Pi}(s)-b(s)| \, ds \right|^2 \right)  \\ &\xrightarrow[]{|\Pi| \to 0} 0. \end{align*}

Comment: For the first part, so you’ve shown that we get a partition independent of each localizing stopping time for $\sigma$. And the same argument gives such partition for $b$. But the proof actually requires the same partitions for $\sigma$ and $b$. How can we make the partitions the same here?

Comment: @nomadicmathematician Are you sure that it is really necessary to have the same partitions? It is certainly more convenient (for notations) but I would suspect that it is not really needed for the proof of the results (... in any case, it is not needed for the proof of the lemma which you stated)

Comment: In the lemma we have the partition $\Pi$ for the Ito process $dX=\sigma dB+bdt$ so it seems to me that the definition of $X^\Pi$ uses a single partition for both $\sigma$ and $b$. Am I incorrect?

Comment: @nomadicmathematician Well, if you had two approximating sequences, say, $g_n$ and $h_n$ with $g_n 1_{[0,\tau_k)} \to \sigma 1_{[0,\tau_k)}$ and $h_n 1_{[0,\tau_k)} \to b 1_{[0,\tau_k)}$ in $L^2$ for each $k$, then the process  $X^{(n)}_t := \int_0^t g_n(s) \, dB_s + \int_0^t h_n(s) \, ds$ will do the job in Lemma 16.4, i.e. $$\mathbb{P} \left( \sup_{t \leq T} |X_t^{(n)}-X_t| > \epsilon \right) \xrightarrow[]{n \to \infty} 0.$$

Comment: (If you really want to have the same partition, then you can also achieve that... if you have two simple functions (with different partitions), then you can refine both of the partitons (i.e. take the "union") and then you will get two simple functions which "live" on the same partition. Not sure whether it's really worth the trouble though...)

Comment: Thank you. The notation $\Pi$ on both sides confused me. Could you help me with the questions I wrote on https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/358093/approximation-of-stochastic-integral?noredirect=1&lq=1 when you have time? With essentially the same proof as above, I can show convergence for $\int_0^t f'(X_s) b(s)ds$, but convergence for $\int_0^t f''(X_s)\sigma^2(s)ds$ is not working because of the square in $\sigma$. And in this answer, I don't follow the details to showing the convergence of $E[\int_0^{T \wedge \tau_n} \sigma^2(s) |f'(X_s^{\Pi}) - f'(X_s)|^2ds] \to 0$.